# cordova mac open URL in safari

Tags: windows, cordova, safari, hyperlink

Am using the following https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-mac to make mac os x apps, but It seems that I cant get _blank links to open. If anyone knows how that would be great.

Answer 1) - did not work

I placed this in WebViewDelegate.m -

> UIWebViewNavigationType < is the error

```
- (BOOL) webView:(WebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the _blank change is a recent one and not yet implemented in iOS. I currently use this piece of native code in `AppDelegate.m` to open external URLs in Safari

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm using this in a Cordova app rather than in a Cordova Mac component. You might need to tweak the code for use in the component rather than the app. Just look for the equivalent method.

Answer (score 0):

**this** worked on 2.3.0 oO'

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
//return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
NSURL *url = [request URL];

// Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
// Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}
else {
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}}
```